# Sum of two lists of newtype

Tags: haskell

I created the type Big Number with the following functions

```
type Digits = [String]
type BigNumber = Digits

scanner :: String->BigNumber
scanner a = map (:[]) a

output :: BigNumber -> String 
output []=""
output a = head a ++ output(tail a)
```

I was trying to make a function that sums two BigNumbers like this:

```
somaBN :: BigNumber -> BigNumber -> BigNumber
somaBN a b = scanner (zipWith (+) (map read a)  (map read b))
```

that is supose to run like this:

> [1,2,3]+[1,2,3]=[2,4,6]

But I get the error:

```
• No instance for (Num Char) arising from a use of ‘+’
• In the first argument of ‘zipWith’, namely ‘(+)’
  In the first argument of ‘scanner’, namely
    ‘(zipWith (+) (map read a) (map read b))’
  In the expression: scanner (zipWith (+) (map read a) (map read b))typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

`zipWith (+) (map read a) (map read b)` is a list of items with a type that is an instance of the `Num` typeclass. It thus makes no sense to use `scanner`, since this takes a `String`.

You thus should convert the numbers back to `String`s with:

```
somaBN :: BigNumber -> BigNumber -> BigNumber
somaBN a b = map … (zipWith (+) (map read a :: Int) (map read b))
```

where you need to fill in `…` which is a function that transforms an `Int` into a `String`, hence `…` has type `… :: Int -> String`.

This will not take care of overflows. Indeed, if you use `somaBN ["9"] ["9"]`, it will return `["18"]`, not `["1", "8"]`. In case you need to work with overflow, likely you should use a recursive function.